# tkinter: simple scrollable text

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label, scrollbar

## Question

I'm trying to make a 'ttk Label' which a) is 20 pixels high by 300 pixels wide, b) is scrollable (in this case horizontally), and c) uses the simplest code possible within reason (except for the fact that the text and scrollbar are both within a frame*). I've found stackoverflow to be helpful in describing the processes I need to go through (put the label in a frame, put the frame in a canvas, put the scroll bar next to or underneath the canvas and 'bind' them together somehow), but despite looking at a fair few docs and stackoverflow questions, I can't figure out why my code isn't working properly. Please could someone a) update the code so that it satisfies the conditions above, and b) let me know if I've done anything unnecessary? Thanks

*the frame will be going in a project of mine, with text that is relevant

## Current code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

myframe_outer = ttk.Frame(root)
mycanvas = tk.Canvas(myframe_outer, height=20, width=300)
myframe_inner = ttk.Frame(mycanvas)
myscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(myframe_outer, orient='horizontal', command=mycanvas.xview)
mycanvas.configure(xscrollcommand=myscroll.set)

myframe_outer.grid()
mycanvas.grid(row=1, sticky='nesw')
myscroll.grid(row=2, sticky='ew')
mycanvas.create_window(0, 0, window=myframe_inner, anchor='nw')
ttk.Label(myframe_inner, text='test ' * 30).grid(sticky='w')

root.mainloop()
```

**Edit:**

## Current result

[image]

Comment: why a canvas with a frame with a label, when you can directly scroll entry and text widgets?

Comment: I had various reasons for not using a text widget, including aesthetics (wanting to stick with ttk where possible), and code readability, as I was going to be repeatedly changing the text using buttons in my actual program, and wanted to use a 'textvariable' instead of repeatedly enabling, deleting, updating and disabling the text widget (as I wanted the text to be readonly, hence wanting to use a 'label')

Comment: My reasons for not wanting to use an entry widget were because I wanted the text to be readonly (I had rashly assumed that 'entry's didn't have a read only option, as it basically makes them labels until they're not readonly) and aesthetics (I wanted whatever scrollable widget I used to look like the other labels in my program, and wasn't aware that readonly entries look very similar to labels)

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you nonetheless as your comment led me to the answer

Comment: That being said, using an 'entry' isn't a long term solution: eventually I'll want to have 2 lines to my text, which I can't do with an entry. Then I'll have to go back to a label.

Answer (score 8):

## Answer

Use a readonly 'entry' widget - it looks the same as a label, and doesn't need to be put in a canvas.

## Code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

mytext = tk.StringVar(value='test ' * 30)

myframe = ttk.Frame(root)
myentry = ttk.Entry(myframe, textvariable=mytext, state='readonly')
myscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(myframe, orient='horizontal', command=myentry.xview)
myentry.config(xscrollcommand=myscroll.set)

myframe.grid()
myentry.grid(row=1, sticky='ew')
myscroll.grid(row=2, sticky='ew')

root.mainloop()
```

## Result

[image]